# escape an asterisk as a Java command line argument in shell

Tags: java, bash, shell

I met a problem when using asterisk as a Java command line argument in shell.
I could simplify the description of this problem as below:

First, There is a simple java program which prints the command line arguments.

```
public class CmdArgsTest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        for(String arg : args)
        {
        System.out.println(arg);    
        }
    }
}
```

When i input: Java CmdArgsTest "s*" in the shell command;

It will not print "s*", but all the file names in the current directory.

I have searched the forum for similar questions and tried to use single quote's*' or backslash 's/*', but all didn't work.

Hope somebody could help me. I appreciate any help.

BTW: Thanks for reminding from Elliott Frisch, I tried this example on Cygwin, I don't know whether it matters

Comment: Try "S\\\*". It should work.

Comment: Not all files, just the ones starting with `s`.

Comment: $ java CmdArgsTest 's\\*', it didn't work also.
Regular expression: "s\\*"

Comment: yes, not all files, just the ones starting with s or S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be fighting with shell [globbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globbing), and your command must have been `java CmdArgsTest s*` to get that behavior

```
$ echo \*
*
$ echo "*"
*
$ echo '*'
*
```

So,

```
java CmdArgsTest "s*"
```

or

```
java CmdArgsTest s\*
```

or

```
java CmdArgsTest 's*'
```

**Edit** (Cygwin)

Use the windows shell escape syntax,

```
"java CmdArgsTest s*"
```

You need to execute commands this way in `cygwin` because `cygwin` is capable of running Windows commands - as noted in the [cygwin](/questions/tagged/cygwin) [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cygwin/info),

> Cygwin provides native integration of Windows-based applications, data, and other system resources with applications, software tools, and data of the Unix-like environment. Thus it is possible to launch Windows applications from the Cygwin environment, as well as to use Cygwin tools and applications within the Windows operating context.

Comment: Believe me I have used java CmdArgsTest "s*" accually. and I know your three echo examples are correct. It just seemed the java program could not get the simple s* as its argument.

Comment: @Jimmy Use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));` and this is how bash (and every unix shell I can think of, even [`fish`](http://fishshell.com/)) works.

Comment: bad luck; i tried, and it didn't work also. if there is s1.txt and s2.txt in the current directory. The display is: [s1.txt, S2.txt]

Comment: @jimmy Unix files are typically case sensitive. What platform is this again?

Comment: my reputaion didn't allow me to post a screenshot, otherwise i may show you the result.

Comment: @Jimmy Yes! Okay. So, that explains part of it (e.g. the mixed case). It might be a cygwin bug.

Comment: @Jimmy Edited. Try the Windows syntax.

Comment: Oh, yes, I believe so! Sorry that i didn't consider the possible influence of Cygwin. Later I will try it on my linux environment. Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it.